# Scroll to the first page when tap the scroll view in the second page

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

Set UIScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES.
DataSource contains four kind of color (red,green,blue,yellow)
Set a page display three kind of color.
So the first page dsiplay red red/green/blue, and the second page display green/blue/yellow.

Problem:
When tap the scroll view in the second page,the scroll view scroll to the first page automatically.

My expected result:
When tap the scroll view in the second page,the scroll view should keep in the second page and do nothing.

My Code:
https://github.com/leogeng/UIScrollView-Paging.git

Comment: What is the question here? Some code would be good too.

Comment: When tap the scroll view in the second page,the scroll view scroll to the first page automatically.It is not my expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

This line of code automatically enable scrollToTop. I don't know if it's possible to disable scrollToTop if paging is enabled.

Comment: Yes,it cause by "scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;", and I do not know how to resolve it.

Comment: scrollview.pagingEnabled = NO; is going to disable scrollToTop.

Comment: You are right,but I need paging,So scrollview.pagingEnabled should be YES.
I add: 
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScrollToTop");
}

When I debug, the code do not run. So It maybe not enable scrolltop.